# How to use php to mark up the semicolon(;) in a string which isn't the end character of the HTML entity?

Tags: php, regex

How can I use PHP to mark up the semicolon mark (;) in a string,
but DO NOT mark up the end character of the HTML entity

For example:

`$string="ab;c&amp;ssdd;;kd&d&quot;ddsskcl;ddfvv";`

Output:
`ab<font color=red><b>;</b></font>c&amp;ssdd<font color=red><b>;</b></font><font color=red><b>;</b></font>kd&d&quot;ddsskcl<font color=red><b>;</b></font>ddfvv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex with a negative lookbehind (ensure the regex before can't be matched, here ; with not &map nor &quot nor &lt not &gt (htmlsplecialchars))
You can play with the following simple regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2bZ8/1)

```
$string="ab;c&amp;ssdd;;kd&d&quot;ddsskcl;ddfvv";
echo preg_replace("/(?<!&amp|&quot|&quote|&lt|&gt);/","<font color=red><b>;</b></font>",$string)."\n";
```

Drawback: you have to make the lookbehind with all alternations.

Good news: You can make a call to [get_html_translation_table](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-html-translation-table.php) to build the pattern like this:

```
$string="ab;c&amp;ssdd;;kd&d&quot;ddsskcl;ddfvv";
$entities = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES); # Get the html entities table
$pat="(?<!"; # Start of the pattern
foreach($entities as $key => $val) {  # Iterate over the html entities
 $pat .= rtrim($val,";")."|"; # concatenate to pattern as an ORED expression
};
$pat=rtrim($pat,"|").");"; # finish the pattern
echo preg_replace("/$pat/","<font color=red><b>;</b></font>",$string)."\n"; # replace where needed
```

Output:

```
> php ./replace.php
ab<font color=red><b>;</b></font>c&amp;ssdd<font color=red><b>;</b></font><font color=red><b>;</b></font>kd&d&quot;ddsskcl<font color=red><b>;</b></font>ddfvv
```

Comment: A simple `str_replace` won't work. It will convert the `;` on the end of `&amp;`.

Comment: Variable length lookbehinds don't compile. You have to separate them out into equal sized lengths: `/(?<!&amp)|(?<!&quot)|(?<!&quote)|(?<!&lt|&gt);/`. Only `&lt` and `&gt` can go together because they are the same length.

Comment: @CJ it works as is as there's fixed length alternatives. What you can't do is (?<!&(amp|quot)) for example because the alternation ends up with different size after & and this is a variable length (common &). See the demo and try it. I had it run on php5.5.

Comment: @Tensibai You are right. My memory is faulty. I was sure I'd seen that cause errors in the past!

Comment: @cj you're not wrong, the lookbehinds have to be fixed size, but alternating inside the lookbehind different fixed size options is the same as alternating multiple lookbehinds at end ;)

Comment: @CJDennis your memory was not faulty, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783991/in-regex-pattern-make-an-error/30784278#30784278)'s a case in python enforcing same size alternations

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to use [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) first, then explode your string into parts and use htmlspecialchars() to re-encode just the text part inside your new tags. It sounds like your markup format isn't very good and you can easily get into a big mess by trying to use regex on HTML/XML.

In general you want to process text as text, not HTML as text or text as HTML. This is why I recommend converting your HTML to text before trying to do any processing on it.

Comment: @Quentin It depends on the input. If only the 3 or 4 XML entities have been encoded then htmlspecialchars_decode is enough. Otherwise, you are perfectly correct! The question only shows `&amp;` and `&quot;` and it's my habit to not encode anything else.

Comment: Best to play it safe when you only have an example of data to work with and not a proper specification.