# "^" in regex pattern make an error

Tags: python, regex

I created a RegEx pattern to find token with `re.compile` and I got an error.

```
error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
```

My pattern is: `(?<=[\s,]|^)(?:\[.*\]|[A-Za-z]+|[0-9a-fA-F]+)(?=[\s,]|$)`
and the error comes from `(?<=[\s,]|^)` and probably from `|^`. But I tried on regex101.com and it works. My `(?=[\s,]|$)` works and `(?<=[\s,]|^)` is pretty much the same so i don't really understand what goes bad.

I use python 3.+ and re lib.

Comment: Error log is quite straightforward - it seems that look-behind (`(?<=...)`) operator in python implementation of regex can be use only with patterns of known width

Comment: It could also be easier to help you, If you explain what your regex should match, or maybe even provide an example of text that should be matched

Comment: They are not the same, look-behind can't have quantifiers (+*?) as they need to be fixed. But your alternation should work as is. A workaround is alternating the lookbehinds like this: `(?:(?<=[\s,])|(?<=^))`

Comment: I want to split asm instruction. So i split where there is "," or space Example `mov ecx, edx`. But i can have `mov [ecx + edx], eax` and in this case i dont want to split inside the bracket. So i prety much want to match hexa number, alpha char and anything inside bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look behind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` are not the same, look-behind can't have quantifiers `+*?` as they need to be fixed size (your error message). But your alternation should work as is.

A workaround for this case is alternating the lookbehinds like this: `(?:(?<=[\s,])|(?<=^))` which make each lookbehind with it's own size.

I suspect a validation rule fighting chars (`\s` or `,`) versus non char `^` for start of line and not allowing it in alternation inside the lookbehind even if it's correct.

Comment: What you suggest me work, but the size is not fixed because i have a "|", right ?

Comment: Yes I suspect the engine to compare `[\s,]` with `^` and thinking ^ is 0 length but [\s,] is of length 1. Try something like `(?<=A|B)C` against `AC` or `BC` and it should work as expected. (I'm not really familiar with python, so I may miss an implementation detail)

Comment: It's probably because "^" is 0 length, because i try with `(?=AB|C)` and i got the same error. Thank you for the solution. =)